# How can I improve speed between buttons tap/click using Selenium Appium python

Tags: ios, selenium, appium, appium-ios, python-appium

I'm learning and writing a script to test an iOS app by using a selenium python script with Appium.

But between two button taps/click some time it can be a little bit long, between each execution.

```
driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Product_Purchase_Button").click()
time.sleep(0.8)#loading page
driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Check_Box_Button").click()
driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Buy_Now_Button").click()
```

I would like to know if I can optimize this part of my code, to click/tap instantly the buttons.

Thank you

Comment: instead of sleep use webdriverwaits: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html

Comment: Thanks do you think it will improve the speed execution between each click ?

Comment: not really... it's a polling loop that polls every 1/2 second.  It'll wait only as long as is needed, so it will be faster than using set sleep times... but your sleep is only .8 so I wouldn't expect a noticeable difference.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no way to improve the speed?

Comment: There's probably ways to optimize your code for IOS/appium.  (Maybe appium itself can be replaced with something faster?)  You might even build a test framework right inside your app.

Comment: What is the optimization you are looking for ? how much time does it take normally with the code you have already ? also use @ to reply.

Comment: I dont really know how much time it take, but as I can see each button take 1s to be clicked, and I would like to do it faster than what the script do atm @cruisepandey